# check all other radio button using one radio button

Tags: javascript, php

i am fetching roll numbers here which have two radio buttons in 'php'.there will be multiple number of roll numbers so i want to check all the radio buttons whose value are 'yes' at once using a particular radio button or check box.although i didn't write that button in this code as i don't know what to write.please give me a solution using java script.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

    echo"<tr><td>{$row['roll']}</td>
    </td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>
    <td><input type='radio' name='present[$i]' value='Yes'>YES</td>
          </td><td></td><td></td><td>
          <td><input type='radio' name='present[$i]' value='No'>NO</td></tr>";
          $i++;

}
```

Comment: You should use javascript to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of interaction should be using a Javascript implementation since it is a client-side operation.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="yes"/>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="no"/>No
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="yes"/>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="no"/>No
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="yes"/>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="no"/>No
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Select All" onclick="selectAll('radio',true);"/>
    <input type="button" value="Deselect All" onclick="selectAll('radio',false);"/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function selectAll( prefix, set ) {
    var form = document.forms[0], //Get the appropriate form
        i = 0,
        radio;
    while( radio = form[prefix + ++i] ) //Loop through all named radio# elements
        for( var j = 0; j < radio.length; j++ ) //Loop through each set of named radio buttons
            if( radio[j].value == (set ? "yes" : "no") ) //Selector based on value of set
                radio[j].checked = true; //Check that radio button!
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KjGj9/)

Comment: its working fine if name is like radio1 .if i want to use a loop then name will like radio[$i]. how can make it work for this type of name?

Comment: But it **is** using a loop to go through the names. It's in the format of `prefix + i` (where `prefix` refers to the string "radio") in the Javascript. If you're talking about the PHP side and creation of those DOM elements, then you will use the following PHP code `$prefix . $i` to denote a name like "radio1" where `$prefix = "radio";` in that case.